# How does this optocoupled smoke sensor circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, homework, multisim, optoelectronics

This is an optocoupler module consisting of an infrared LED coupled to a phototransistor as smoke sensor.

[image]

I got this circuit from [this site.](https://www.electroschematics.com/smart-smoke-sensor-alarm/)

According to T.K. Hareendran says:

> For optimum performance, adjust trimpots P1, P2 and the value of resistor R1.

I don't understand this part.

Comment: (1) What do you not understand? Please [edit] your question to explain so that someone doesn't waste their time writing about stuff that you already know. (2) The component values are given in the schematic so what do you need calculated? (3) If that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).)

Comment: I apologize I have no idea about that I tried to edit my question but I couldn't and regarding the drawing it's not mine I got it from this site: https://www.electroschematics.com/smart-smoke-sensor-alarm/  and I don't understand the whole drawing.

Comment: Use the [edit] link below your question or the one in this comment. "I don't understand the whole drawing." Do you mean you understand none of it? What level of electronics have you studied?

Comment: The linked article explains how the circuit works. Pick one item from that article that you don't understand and ask (in your question) for an explanation. Again, note that the component values are given on the schematic so either remove that part or explain what part you are asking about.

Comment: I'm a beginner right now I only studied about bjt and mosfets

Comment: Start with something simpler?

Comment: The problem is that's what the assignment ask for

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far? What does the teacher and textbook tell you about the subject?

Comment: Note that putting the light and sensor on the same axis a really poor design, you need thick smoke to block the sensor enough to be detected. A real smoke detector has the light and sensor at right-angles and detects the *scattering* of light due to the particles in smoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mattman944 has mentioned in a comment, this design will not trigger until the smoke is very dense.

The efficiency of LEDs and phototransistors will vary from batch to batch.  So it's not possible to design a circuit with fixed resistors that will work reliably.  So you will need to adjust the two variable resistors P1 and P2 up or down so that the alarm doesn't go off if these is no smoke, but does sound if there is smoke.